# Error while running apt-get update with GCSFuse installed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I have GCSFuse installed on my machine and I am seeing the following error while running sudo apt-get update command.

```
E: Repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-focal InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'gcsfuse-jessie' to 'namespaces/gcs-fuse-prod/repositories/gcsfuse-focal'
E: Repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-focal InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'gcsfuse-jessie' to 'namespaces/gcs-fuse-prod/repositories/gcsfuse-focal'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

I was wondering if this is intentional or something changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin and label were changed because the backend used to host these packages changed. This is an intentional change. Please use one of the following commands to run apt-get update:

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

OR

```
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt-get update
```

This should be a one-time problem. Any following apt-get commands should work fine.